# linked list operation with multi threads

Tags: c

I have the following code snippet for linked list operation:

```
#define MPL_DL_APPEND_NP(head,add,_next,_prev)                                                 \
do {                                                                                           \
  if (head) {                                                                                  \
      (add)->_prev = (head)->_prev;                                                            \
      (head)->_prev->_next = (add);                                                            \
      (head)->_prev = (add);                                                                   \
      (add)->_next = NULL;                                                                     \
  } else {                                                                                     \
      (head)=(add);                                                                            \
      (head)->_prev = (head);                                                                  \
      (head)->_next = NULL;                                                                    \
  }                                                                                            \
} while (0)
```

If multi threads are updating this linked list concurrently, is there any issue? Suppose I have two threads in my program, and each thread needs to append one node to this link list. What will be the possible finial linked list?

Comment: why on earth is this a macro instead of a function?

Comment: First: add backslashes. Second: don't do it.

Comment: Yes, that was backslash. It's just copy and paste issue. This part of code is in critical section. I have to put it either inside macro or as inline function for performance reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a problem. Assume you have one node and two threads.

Let's say that both of them are ready to insert a node. Which one comes first? Do they have to do with a list of one node or with a list of two nodes. In general you don't exactly what will happen!

The insertion in your list (where the list is visible to all threads) is called a critical section and should be handled as such!

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's an issue. It's possible `if(head) {` will be executed for both, and for each `add`, the previous will be the current `head`. Now you have an ill-defined list, that's more like a tree.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there will be problems. If you are working with multiple threads on the same peace of memory. At some point you will end up with unexpected results for sure.

Consider using [locks](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_mutex_init.html) and [semaphores](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html) to get rid of any possible race conditions.